# Trying to get property of non-object while using num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the code that has been giving me the following error.

```
Trying to get property of non-object in G:\xampp\htdocs\abc\admin\delete.php on line 68
```

Here's the code,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    include '../includes/db.php';

    $sql = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE aid= '".$_POST['aid']. "'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $count = $result->num_rows;

    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }

    $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

db.php has the code that connects to the database.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fgfg";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

It executes the query but the error message is displayed.

What is causing it?

Comment: where you open connection "$conn" ?

Comment: What is at line no 68?

Comment: @Apb `$count = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: `$conn->mysqli_query($sql);` ?

Comment: Specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you delete what you need to return is `affected_rows`.
On Delete query it gives affected rows not num rows.

Use `$conn->affected_rows` instead of `$result->num_rows`

Please refer [Affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

**Edit:** You need to pass connection string not result.

Comment: Using `$result->affected_rows` gives the same error.

Comment: Is row deleted from table? Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes the row is deleted.

Comment: @innowqhy: post your database connection code

Comment: updated my post with db.php code.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check

Comment: _You need to pass connection string not result_ I'm sorry I don't get it.

Comment: Instead of `$result->affected_rows` you need to use `$conn->affected_rows`. I updated it in answer